# How can I apply such effects to watermark text to photo using image intervention in php?

Tags: php, laravel, intervention

I have added text watermark to images. I want to make text effect like shown in image below (First one). I am using hollow fonts. Example code is

```
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// use callback to define details
$img->text('water-mark-text', 0, 0, function($font) {
    $font->file('font.ttf');
    $font->size(24);
    $font->color(array(255, 255, 255, 0.5))
    $font->align('center');
    $font->valign('top');
});
```

[image]

Comment: i think you cant. You can set font styles for plaintexts. but you can add filters for images. my best guess is adding a styled image would be the correct way to go.

Comment: @Sithira I hear you, what would it be like when I am adding dynamic text and placing that by calculating aspect ratio of the target image ?